# SqlDataReader: Combine Records in One String with Delimeters

Tags: sqldatareader

I would like to combine 2 or more records in a single string based from SqlDataReader data.

```
SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string category = "";
while (data.Read())
{
    category = data["Column1"].ToString() + ", " + category;
}
ltCategory.Text = category.TrimEnd(',');
```

I have 2 existing records and the ltCategory.Text displays **Record1, Record2,**

I want to use the following format:

- Record1
- Record1, Record2, Record3

**SOLUTION**

```
SqlDataReader data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
string category = "";
while (data.Read())
{
    category += ", " + data["Column1"].ToString();
}
ltCategory.Text = category.TrimStart(',');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `category = data["Column1"].ToString() + ", " + category;` to `category += data["Column1"].ToString() + ", ";`

```
ltCategory.Text = category.TrimEnd(',');
```

This might need to be changed as well to:

```
ltCategory.Text = category.TrimEnd(', ');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot add more than one character inside the TrimEnd().

Comment: The comma is still visible in the end of the string.

Comment: `category += data["Column1"].ToString() + "," + " ";`

Then outside of your loop:

`categoryText = category.TrimEnd('');
ltCategory.Text = categoryText.TrimEnd(',');`

Note the most elegant of solutions however. You could alternativaly have the whitespace at the start of the += and perform a TrimStart.